# После декомпиляции пропадают методы

Tags: java, android

После разборки апк некоторые методы в файлах становятся такими. 
Скрин https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3HqA/ArA8vQMkZ

Это что за защита такая? Или это от версии aptoll зависит?